# How can I know the drop has been accepted

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

In my Cocoa App 1.0, My view conforms to NSDraggingSource, So I use

```
- (NSArray *)namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination
```

to judge whether the drop has been accepted and I also can get the dropDestination'URL.

Now in my Cocoa App 2.0, I notice that this method has identified as deprecated.

I don't know where to judge whether the drop has been accepted and get the dropDestination'URL without the deprecated method.

somebody can help me how to do that with the new method?

=================================================================================

[image]

Comment: Have you tested if `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:`gives you success or denial in its operation parameter?

Comment: @Volker `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:` has identified as deprecated too so it would be best not use it?

Comment: sorry, ... my error: `draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` was what I meant. mistyped out of habit.

Comment: @Volker  I test it. Cancel the drag will also go the `draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` method

Comment: Yes, but how is the operation set?

Comment: @Volker It will be NSDragOperationNone.Looks like I can judge by this? And how to get destination's URL when I drag to Finder?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47727/discussion-between-crazy-catcher-and-volker)